# combing multiple csv rows onto one based on a field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have my csv data as below,

```
+----------+--+--+--+--+--------------------------+---------+-------+
| Username |  |  |  |  |        SchoolName        |  Type   | Count |
+----------+--+--+--+--+--------------------------+---------+-------+
| corinne  |  |  |  |  | Brentwood School         | Comment |     1 |
| corinne  |  |  |  |  | 1st Cerebral Palsy of Nj | Comment |     3 |
| corinne  |  |  |  |  | Campbell Hall School     | Like    |     1 |
| ed       |  |  |  |  | Campbell Hall School     | View    |     5 |
| ed       |  |  |  |  | Campbell Hall School     | Like    |     2
| ed       |  |  |  |  | 1st Cerebral Palsy of Nj | View    |     3 |
| corinne  |  |  |  |  | 1st Cerebral Palsy of Nj | View    |     1 |
| corinne  |  |  |  |  | 1st Cerebral Palsy of Nj | Like    |     1 |
+----------+--+--+--+--+--------------------------+---------+-------+
```

The report shows the views, likes and comments of each particular user for videos tagged with the mentioned school, is it possible to change the report so that it would show the different counts as 3 different columns, for each user for the particular school based on type?
like,

```
Username    SchoolName              viewCount likeCount commentCount

corinne     1st Cerebral Palsy of Nj       1         1          3
ed          Campbell Hall School           5         2          0
```

the data is obtained from a mongo aggregate query, I've pasted the code if it helps. Thanks

```
activity.aggregate([
               { "$match": {createdAt:{$gte:new Date(fromDate), $lte:new Date(toDate)}}},
               { "$unwind": "$category"},
               { "$lookup": {
                 "localField": "user_id",
                 "from": "users",
                 "foreignField": "_id",
                 "as":"users"
               } },
               { "$unwind": "$users" },
               { "$lookup": {
                 "localField": "category",
                 "from": "categories",
                 "foreignField": "_id",
                 "as":"schools"
               } },
                { "$unwind": "$schools" },
                { "$match":matchFilter},
                {"$group": {_id:{user:"$users.username", user_id:"$users._id", firstName:"$users.firstName", lastName:"$users.lastName", email:"$users.email",schoolName:"$schools.name",type:"$type"},
                           "count": { $sum: 1 }}}
             ], function(err, totalStats){
                var finalTotal=[];
                async.each(totalStats,function(total,callback){
                  finalTotal.push({Username:total._id.user, FirstName:total._id.firstName,
                   LastName:total._id.lastName, Email:total._id.email, UserId:total._id.user_id,SchoolName:total._id.schoolName,Type:total._id.type, Count:total.count})
                   callback()
                },function(err){
                  if(finalTotal.length>=1){
                    var result=json2csv({data:finalTotal})
                  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, you just need to change the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline to accommodate the counts using the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator, which will feed to **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** a count value depending on the **`$type`** field.

For example:

```
activity.aggregate([
    { "$match": {createdAt:{$gte:new Date(fromDate), $lte:new Date(toDate)}}},
    { "$unwind": "$category"},
    { "$lookup": {
        "localField": "user_id",
        "from": "users",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as":"users"
    } },
    { "$unwind": "$users" },
    { "$lookup": {
        "localField": "category",
        "from": "categories",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as":"schools"
    } },
    { "$unwind": "$schools" },
    { "$match":matchFilter},
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "username": "$users.username", 
                "schoolName": "$schools.name"
            },
            "viewCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$type", "View" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "likeCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$type", "Like" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "commentCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$type", "Comment" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "Username": "$_id.username",
            "SchoolName": "$_id.schoolName",
            "_id": 0, "viewCount": 1, "likeCount": 1, "commentCount": 1
        }
    }
], function(err, totalStats){
    console.log(totalStats);
    var result=json2csv({data:totalStats})
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a ton :)